# Cómo puedo validar correctamente un argumento?

Tags: vba, ms-access

Estoy realizando una validación de usuarios, pero tengo un problema con el Dlookup y el argumento pasado como parámetro.

Tabla Roles, con los siguientes campos y tipos de datos.

```
IdNivel, Integer
NivelUsuario, Texto
Permisos, Si/No
Datos, Si/No
Reportes, Si/No
```

Variable global `strNivel` tipo `integer`

En el formulario Login paso el IdNivel del nivel de usuario con

```
in Dlookup.
strNivel = DLookup("Nivel", "Usuarios", "IdUsuario ='" & Me.txtUsuario.Value & "'")
```

Paso el parametro al formulario principal

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "Main", , , , , , strNivel
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "Login"
```

Hasta aquí todo bien, el problema lo tengo al dar clic a un botón del formulario principal, trato de validar si tiene o no acceso ese formulario validando el argumento pasado como parámetro así.

```
If DLookup("Datos", "Roles", "strNivel=" & Me.OpenArgs & "") = True Then
Msgbox "Abre Form"
Else
Msgbox "No tiene acceso"
End If
```

Este es el codigo que me tira error, `2471 la expresion ingresada como parametro de consulta produce el error '*strNivel*'`

Claro no puede faltar en el evento al abrir formulario validar si pasa o no el argumento.

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
If IsNull(Me.OpenArgs) Then
MsgBox "Sin acceso", vbCritical, "Warning"
End If
End Sub
```

Alguna sugerencia cual puede ser el error?

Comment: En `DoCmd.OpenForm "Main", , , , , , strNivel DoCmd.Close acForm, "Login"` pasas el texto `Login` como `OpenArgs` del formulario. Y luego haces `"strNivel=" & Me.OpenArgs & ""` cuando antes has dicho que `strNivel` es de tipo Integer. Estás metiendo un texto en una variable numérica.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok... esta bien, solo que lo que te falta es una variable booleana, estas asignando a un If el Dlookup, lo correcto seria asi:

```
    ''Variable que servira para la validacion
    Dim Respuesta As Boolean
    
    Respuesta = CBool(DLookup("Datos", "Roles", "strNivel=" & Me.OpenArgs & ""))
    
    ''Validamos la variable.
    If Nz(Respuesta, False) Then
        MsgBox "Abre Form."
    Else
        MsgBox "No tiene Acceso."
    End If
```